# Spark MlLib Frequent Pattern Mining, type parameter bounds

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have data in a key,value pairing the key is the column index and the value is whatever is in that columns value. My original file is just a csv. So I have the following:

```
val myData = sc.textFile(file1)
  .map(x => x.split('|'))
  .flatMap(x => x.zipWithIndex)
  .map(x => x.swap)
  .groupByKey().cache
```

This puts my data into myData: Array[(Int, Iterable[String])]

```
val fpg = new FPGrowth()
  .setMinSupport(0.2)
  .setNumPartitions(1)

val model = fpg.run(myData)
```

I get the following issues:

```
<console>:29: error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,(Int, Iterable[String])] do not conform to method run's type parameter bounds [Item,Basket <: Iterable[Item]]
```

I am trying to learn how to use MlLib, and don't quite understand the issue. I've also tried removing the index and .map(x=>x._2) and making sets of just the iterable data but that also fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
fpg.run(myData.values.map(_.toArray))
```

Basically `FPGrowth` requires an `Array` of `Items`. Passing output from `groupByKey` won't work because it contains `Tuple2`, output from `map(x => x._2)` won't work because value is not an `Array`.

Each element of the RDD represents a single basket and should contain only the unique items. If you expect duplicates you can use `_.toSet.toArray` or `_distinct.toArray`.

Comment: Thanks, also I am getting this org.apache.spark.SparkException (Items in a transaction must be unique but got WrappedArray(T, T, T, T, ..) [duplicate 2] is it because the array contains all T's and ntohing else?

Comment: No, it is because you have duplicate entries. Input like this doesn't make sense for `FPGrowth`.

Comment: In a basket yes. `fpg.run(myData.values.map(_.toSet.toArray))`

Comment: So something like this would be more appropriate? val model = fpg.run(myData.values.distinct.map(_.toArray))

Comment: No. Each entry in a RDD you pass to `FPGrowth` is a single basket. You don't want duplicates in a basket because every basket which contains item `T` has to contain `T`. There is no useful rule here :) You want duplicate baskets because this is an useful information. This is one of the things that make itemsets frequent.